# EF Core complex Where

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an MVC project using EF Core . In my controller , I'm recieving parameters by url , one of them is `searchQuery` . I have a table of customers in this format:

```
id | empId | empName | personId | personFirstName | personLastName
```

Note that a customer is either an employer, or a person , not both. (the corresponding fields will be NULL). This is the query I'm using :

```
collectionBeforePaging = _context.Customers
    .Where(a => (a.Employer == null ? (a.Person.FirstName.Contains(searchQueryForWhereClause) ||
                                       a.Person.LastName.Contains(searchQueryForWhereClause) ||
                                       a.PersonId.ToString().Contains(searchQueryForWhereClause))
                                    : (a.Employer.Name.Contains(searchQueryForWhereClause) ||
                                       a.EmployerId.ToString().Contains(searchQueryForWhereClause))));
```

This work, though not the way I want. If the user search for "Jhon Pots" , and the customer is a person, then it will check if the first name contains "Jhon Pots" or the last name does, instead of checking if first name contains "Jhon" and last name contains "Pots" .

I can concat `firstName` and `lastName` , but then it will have to be an exact match (I.E. It won't match a customer named "Jhon S. Pots")

I also thought about breaking down the searchQuery using the `Split` method, but I don't know how to combine it with EF Where clause correctly .. (I can't use a foreach loop and filter for each string, since it will filter my result by each string instead of using the `OR` logical operator)

Does anyone have idea how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split your string first, and then query based on whether any of the items in the resulting array match each field:

```
var keywords = searchQuery.Split(' ');
```

Then:

```
collectionBeforePaging = _context.Customers
    .Where(a => a.Employer == null
        ? keywords.Any(k => 
            a.Person.FirstName.Contains(k) ||
            a.Person.LastName.Contains(k) ||
            a.PersonId.ToString().Contains(k))
         : keywords.Any(k =>
            a.Employer.Name.Contains(k) ||
            a.EmployerId.ToString().Contains(k)));
```

Comment: Although I've used a different approach because of performance preferences, this is exactly what I was looking for , so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To perform db side like comparison you may use the [EF.Functions.Like()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-2.1) method.

Split the search terms with space as delimiter, iterate the search terms and add where clause to the query before executing:

```
string[] searchTerms = searchQueryForWhereClause.Split(' ');

var query = _context.Customers.AsQueryable();
foreach (string searchTerm in searchTerms)
{
    query = query.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.FirstName, $"%{searchTerm}%"
        || EF.Functions.Like(x.LastName, $"%{searchTerm}%"
        || EF.Functions.Like(x.PersonId, $"%{searchTerm}%"
        || EF.Functions.Like(x.Employer.Name, $"%{searchTerm}%"
        || EF.Functions.Like(x.EmployerId, $"%{searchTerm}%");
}
```

Comment: thanks! as they broke the old/new way of doing it in ef core 5 so annoying, aka `files = files.Where(x => searchTerms.Any(y => x.OriginalFilename.Contains(y)));` something like this does not work in ef 5, used to work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your Customers table has a unique id. Perform a split on the search string, and for each split just return a list of actual customer ids. Add the ids together in a list, then use that list of ids to get the customers that match

Comment: That what I was trying to avoid .. The code is getting too messy :\